# Trouble installing "car" package in R.

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu, rstudio

I had used this to try to install the car package:

```
install.packages("car", dependencies=TRUE, INSTALL_opts = c('--no-lock'))
```

but received this error:

```
ERROR: dependency ‘openxlsx’ is not available for package ‘rio’ 
* removing ‘/home/dan-laptop/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rio’
Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘rio’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’
* removing ‘/home/dan-laptop/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/car’
Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘car’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘car’ is not available for package ‘alr4’
* removing ‘/home/dan-laptop/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/alr4’
Warning in install.packages :
   installation of package ‘alr4’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried installing the dependencies individually with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What error message do you get when you directly install openxlsx?

Comment: Update R. openxlsx [requires at least R 3.3.0](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/openxlsx/index.html).

Comment: Gotcha. I'm running 3.2.3, I'll update and see if that fixes it.